# using django inline formset to add multiple files

Tags: django, django-forms

I want to be able to add multiple images to my Scribble model. That is why I put ScribbleMedia into a separate model so that I can use it as a foreign key and then with django Formset I want to be able to add multiple files to one Scribble model.

The examples I've seen so far would let me make multiple Scribble models but I am not sure how to go about just adding multiple FileFields to one Scribble.

Here is the code:

## Models.py

```
class Scribble(models.Model):
         body = models.TextField()
         user = models.ForeignKey(User)
         def __unicode__(self):
          return u'%s, %s' % (self.user.username, self.media)

def get_file_path(instance, filename):
      ext = filename.split('.')[-1]
      filename = "%s.%s" % (uuid.uuid4(), ext)
      return os.path.join('scribblemedia/', filename)

class ScribbleMedia(models.Model):
     media = models.FileField(upload_to=get_file_path)
     scribble=models.ForeignKey(Scribble)
     def __unicode__(self):
      return self.media
```

## forms.py

```
class ScribbleSaveForm(forms.Form):
    media=forms.FileField(
      label=u'add file',
      required=False,
      widget=forms.FileInput()
    )
    body=forms.CharField(
      label=u'description',
      widget=forms.Textarea()
    )
```

## views.py

```
def scribbler_save_page(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ScribbleSaveForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            #Create or get media.
            media, dummy = ScribbleMedia.objects.get_or_create(
                media=form.cleaned_data['media']
            )
            #Create or get media.
            scribble, created=Scribble.objects.get_or_create(
                user=request.user,
                media=media
            )
            #update scribble body
            scribble.body=form.cleaned_data['body']
            # Save scribble to database.
            scribble.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect ( 
                '/user/%s/' % request.user.username
            )
    else:
        form = ScribbleSaveForm()
    variables = RequestContext (request, { 
        'form': form
    })
    return render_to_response ('scribble_save.html', variables)
```

## scribble_save.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
    {% block title %}Save Scribble {% endblock %}
    {% block head %}Save Scribble {% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action=".">
        {{ form.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" value="save" />
        {% csrf_token %}
    </form>
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your model structure is wrong: what you have would allow one ScribbleMedia to have multiple Scribbles, which is the opposite of what you want. Move the ForeignKey to the ScribbleMedia model, so it points at Scribble.

Secondly, as you note, this is the exact use-case of an [inline formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets). You don't say exactly what trouble you're having with that, but the documentation should be clear: your inline model in your case has just a single field (the `media` filefield), so you aren't adding multiple files to one Scribble, you're adding multiple ScribbleMedias - each of which with a single FileField - to one Scribble.

Comment: Thanks for the response Daniel.
I did fix the model the way you said it should be. But I am very confused in how I should handle the rest of my files. I am sorry I am new to Django and python itself, thats why I am having so much troubles.